# Simple Javascript "undefined" question

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm iterating over a bunch of child nodes and checking to see if they are actually visible on the page with this statement:

```
if(child.offsetWidth == 0 || child.offsetHeight == 0 || child.style.visibility == 'hidden'     || child.style.display == 'none'){
```

child is defined in the loop so that's not an issue.

What is an issue is that elements might not have a style attribute defined and so javascript returns "child.style" not defined.

How do I do a seemingly simple if statement like this without it stopping because something is not defined?

I tried doing this:

```
if(undefined !== child.style){ var addquery = "child.style.visibility == 'hidden' ||     child.style.display == 'none'"; }
if(child.offsetWidth == 0 || child.offsetHeight == 0 || addquery){
console.debug(child);
}
```

But I think addquery is just evaluating to true and not working.

Comment: That thing with "addquery" absolutely will not work; you can't stash strings containing code in variables and then use them as code fragments. The language simply does not support that.

Comment: Heh, yeah...sort of realized that.  Was just digging, you know...gotta try stuff before asking questions!  The answers here are helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(child.offsetWidth == 0 || child.offsetHeight == 0 || (child.style && (child.style.visibility == 'hidden' || child.style.display == 'none')))
```

Since `&&` is a [short-circuit operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), it will only evaluate `child.style.visibility == 'hidden' || child.style.display == 'none'` if `child.style` evaluates to `true`, meaning that `child.style` *exists*, and therefore can be accessed. If `child.style` evaluates to `false`, the rest will just be ignored; `child.style` won't be accessed, and therefore no errors will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

If `this.child` is `undefined`, the next part between `&& (` and `)` won't be evaluated.

```
if(child.offsetWidth == 0 || child.offsetHeight == 0 || typeof child.style != 'undefined' && (child.style.visibility == 'hidden' || child.style.display == 'none')){
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `undefined` as a keyword, because it doesn't exist in JavaScript.

However, because every variable initially *is* undefined then testing against a non-existent `undefined` variable does often work. However:

```
var undefined = 5; // this could be anywhere in the code

// [...]

if(foo === undefined) // *not* the test you want to be checking
```

Instead, use `typeof foo == "undefined"`. Only an actually undefined variable will return the string `"undefined"` from the typeof operator

Comment: Not quite. `undefined` always exists, since it is defined as a property of the global object, with a value of `undefined`. If `undefined` really didn't exist, `if ("foo" == undefined) {}` would throw a `ReferenceError`. There is a big difference between a variable never having been declared and one that has been declared but has a value of `undefined`.  However, you're correct that `undefined` can be assigned to and is therefore unreliable.

Comment: Something cool is the way that jQuery gets its hands on `undefined`: `(function( window, undefined ) { /* 6000 lines */ })(window);`

Answer (score 1):

Check the `nodeType` property of each child. If the child is an element, it is guaranteed to have a `style` property and there's no need to check whether it's undefined. Your code makes it clear that it's only elements that you're interested in, so you should make sure you only deal with elements.

```
if ((child.nodeTye == 1) && [...all the other conditions...]) {...}
```

Also, checking the `display` and `visibility` properties of an element's `style` property won't tell you whether the element is actually visible on the page or not, since the `style` object only conatins values set explictly on the element via the `style` attribute or the `style` property. You need to check the computed value of `display` and `visibility` instead, which you can do with [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) (or the element's `currentStyle` property in IE).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your code to be stopped because of an error (like `x.style.display` with `x.style` undefined will trigger an exception), but your code could keep going, just use a `try catch`

```
   try {
        ...child.style.visibility...
   } catch(e) {
        // do either nothing or set child.style for instance
   }
```

this way the code is not stopped, you have a way to catch a problem, and also a way to fix it.